# Understanding the translation of ～てほしいと頼まれました

Tags: grammar, て-form

> 早稲田大学｛わせだだいがく｝の新聞部員｛しんぶんぶいん｝である日本人｛にほんじん｝の友達｛ともだち｝に、今、「世界｛せかい｝の大学｛だいがく｝」というテーマのシリーズを組｛く｝んでいるので、**あなたにはアメリカの大学｛だいがく｝について投稿｛とうこう｝してほしいと頼｛たの｝まれました。**

I interpreted the first part of that sentence is that the speaker is going to write a series called "World Universities" for their friend at Waseda University, but the second part confuses me a bit.

I know it's supposed to say something like "I was asked to have you write the article", but I'm confused about how it is phrased with してほしいと頼まれました. I feel like it should have another verb in there to show that the person speaking is asking a question, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of a long [direct speech with brackets omitted](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30585/5010).

> 早稲田大学の新聞部員である日本人の友達に、「今、『世界の大学』というテーマのシリーズを組んでいるので、あなたにはアメリカの大学について投稿してほしい」と頼まれました。

The main structure of the sentence is:

> (私は)日本人の友達に「...」と頼まれました。
>   "I was asked by a Japanese friend, (who said "...")

... and everything in the brackets is what this Japanese friend said to the speaker. It's the Japanese friend who is going to publish articles about universities in the world, and あなた in the sentence refers to the speaker, who is presumably American.